# How can I clear the current command?

Tags: banished

Whenever I perform any action that involves building or planning something, the act of left clicking changes its function (generally to mark that I am indeed building something in the said location). After I set one of those things, though, my cursor is still replaced with the new command. I don't need more than one fishing building, or gathering building, right now.

How do I "clear" my cursor so that it goes back to letting me select things to inspect them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To revert to *Inspect*, simply press the Right Mouse Button.

Generally, RMB is used to cancel *any* cursor activity in *Banished*.

Comment: To the Low Quality Queue I go!

Comment: You have to right click *twice* to free the cursor from the previous activity if you were just marking areas for resource removal.

Comment: @Lumberjack I have noticed that there are some commands that require double cancelling, yes. I haven't quite figured out what causes that, though.

Comment: Commands that select a variable area (crops, roads, harvesting tool) require you to press RMB twice to get out of it if you were highlighting something.